# Error in `vec_as_location()`: using pivot_wider

Tags: r, tidyr

I have data that looks like this;

```
v<-as.numeric(c(rep(c(1,2,3), 3)))
n<-as.factor(c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3)))
t<-data.frame(v, n)
str(t)
```

I am using the tidyr version 1.1.4. inside RStudio version 2021.9.0.351. I am using `pivot_wider()` to go from long to wide format like this;

```
t.wide<-t%>%pivot_wider(names_from=n, values_from=v)
```

But I get this error code;

```
Error in `vec_as_location()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• call = call
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is likely related to a problem with the vctrs package; updating the package with `install.packages("vctrs")` may fix the issue. For the pivot, you can use:

```r
library(tidyr)

v<-as.numeric(c(rep(c(1,2,3), 3)))
n<-as.factor(c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3)))
t<-data.frame(v, n)
str(t)
#> 'data.frame':    9 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ v: num  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
#>  $ n: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3

t %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = n,
              values_from = v,
              values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(a, b, c))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     2     2     2
#> 3     3     3     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @jared_mamrot. My expected output should look like your second example. However, when I copy and past both of your examples I am getting the same error.

Comment: Perhaps try updating the vctrs package? (i.e. `install.packages("vctrs")`)

Comment: it worked!!!! Thank you so much! If you add that to your answer I will mark it as resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Dustin, glad you solved your problem.